# try to build mega menu on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor, megamenu

I have built a mega menu with elementskit but it would not appear on my menu on my website what should i do?(i built heaer and footer with elementskit so that is not the problem)
please if you know any other way to build a mega menu tell me
theme maga menu did not work either

I have built a mega menu with elementskit but it would not appear on my menu

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.